# How to add and remove CSS using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

[tree-view file explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8b0Y.png)

I'm a beginner using Vanilla JS and want some advice on how to approach adding/removing "files"/CSS in the content section based on what folder I click on the left: If I click on the 'about' folder, only 'about.txt' is in the content section. If I click on the 'projects' folder, only the project files are displayed in the content section, etc.

I've been trying to solve this for almost 3 days now, and can't find any stack question that could help.

So I was able to (kinda) get the first step down, as I made a filter using a loop that looks through all the files and finds the file I input, and removes the others:

```
// function that removes the files
function removeContent(contentFile) {
  contentFile.remove();
}

// function that looks for the 'specificContentFile' I input, and removes each file that doesn't match the found file
function findFile(specificContentFile) {
  let grabFiles = document.getElementsByClassName("content-file")
  let foundFile = grabFiles[specificContentFile];
  for (let i = grabFiles.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (grabFiles[i] !== foundFile) {
      removeContent(grabFiles[i]);
    }
  }
}

// event listener that runs the above function when I click on the about tab (same for each tab)
openAboutTab.addEventListener('click', () => {
  findFile("about-file");
})
```

But I ran into some problems with this one as if I continue to flip through the folders, the content section eventually turns blank since I don't add all the folders back. I tried making a similar function to removeContent but instead using .add(), but I figured out that didn't work the way I thought it would. Another problem with this method is that I can only filter for **one** file, and the project files wouldn't be together. I couldn't figure out a work-around to this either.

I thought about just scrapping this loop thing and just using pseudoclasses to show/hide content sections based on what I click, but I really want to figure this out. Help is appreciated :)

Here's the repo if you want to try it out for yourself: https://github.com/c-rti/modal-test

Sample from link as snippet:

```js
const openModalButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-modal-target]')
const closeModalButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-close-button]')
const overlay = document.getElementById('overlay')

const openAboutTab = document.getElementById('about-tab')
const openProjectsTab = document.getElementById('projects-tab')
const openContactTab = document.getElementById('contact-tab')

function openModal(modal) {
  if (modal == null) return
  modal.classList.add('active')
  overlay.classList.add('active')
}

function closeModal(modal) {
  if (modal == null) return
  modal.classList.remove('active')
  overlay.classList.remove('active')
}


openModalButtons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const modal = document.querySelector(button.dataset.modalTarget)
    openModal(modal)
  })
})

overlay.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const modals = document.querySelectorAll('.window.active')
  modals.forEach(modal => {
    closeModal(modal)
  })
})

closeModalButtons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const modal = button.closest('.window')
    closeModal(modal)
  })
})

function addContent(contentFile) {
  tr.appendChild(contentFile);
}

function removeContent(contentFile) {
  contentFile.remove();
}



function findFile(specificContentFile) {
  let grabFiles = document.getElementsByClassName("content-file")
  let foundFile = grabFiles[specificContentFile];
  for (let i = grabFiles.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (grabFiles[i] !== foundFile) {
      removeContent(grabFiles[i]);
    }
  }
}

openAboutTab.addEventListener('click', () => {
  findFile("about-file");
})

openProjectsTab.addEventListener('click', () => {
  findFile("project-file-1");
})

openContactTab.addEventListener('click', () => {
  findFile("contact-file");
})
```

```css
* {
  font-family: "MS Sans Serif", Arial;
}

#menu-list {
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.menu-item {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0 3px;
}

.menu-item::first-letter {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.menu {
  margin: 3px;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.status-bar {
  column-gap: 2px;
}

#all-folders {
  max-width: 40%
}

#contents {
  max-width: 60%;
}

#status-bar {
  gap: 2px;
  row-gap: 2px;
}

#objects {
  width: 45%;
}

#memory-space {
  width: 20%;
}

#selected-name {
  width: 35%;
}

.window {
  z-index: 10;
  min-width: 40%;
  max-width: 80%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
}

.window.active {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1.5px;
  width: 100%;
}

.tree-view {
  width: 40%;
  max-width: 40%;
}

.sunken-panel {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60%;
}

#overlay {
  position: fixed;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  pointer-events: none;
}

#overlay.active {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: all;
}

li:focus {
  outline: 1px dotted #000000;
}

.tree-view {
  cursor: default;
}

tr {
  display: flex;
  margin: 2px 2px;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.content-file {
  min-height: 48px;
  max-height: 48px;
  padding: 6px 6px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: fit-content;
}

#notes-icon {
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 3.5px auto;
  max-height: 32px;
  max-width: 32px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/98.css" />
  <!--  commented out and included in snippet  <link rel="stylesheet" href="modal.css"/>
    
    <script defer src="modal.js"></script>
    -->

</head>

<body>
  <a data-modal-target="#modal">test</a>
  <div class="window" id="modal">
    <div class="title-bar">
      <div class="title-bar-text">A Window With A Status Bar</div>
      <div class="title-bar-controls">
        <button aria-label="Help"></button>
        <button data-close-button aria-label="Close" class="close-button"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
      <ul id="menu-list">
        <li class="menu-item">File</li>
        <li class="menu-item">Edit</li>
        <li class="menu-item">View</li>
        <li class="menu-item">Tools</li>
        <li class="menu-item">Help</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="status-bar" id="status-bar">
      <p class="status-bar-field" id="all-folders">All Folders</p>
      <p class="status-bar-field" id="contents">
        Contents of '<span></span>'
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <ul class="tree-view" id="folder-list">
        <li>
          <details open>
            <summary>My Computer</summary>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <details open>
                  <summary>(C:)</summary>
                  <ul class="tree-view-folders">
                    <li><a id="about-tab">about</a></li>
                    <li><a id="projects-tab">projects</a></li>
                    <li><a id="contact-tab">contact</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </details>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </details>
        </li>
        <li>
          <details open>
            <summary>Secret Documents</summary>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <details>
                  <summary>DO NOT OPEN</summary>
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                      <details closed>
                        <summary>LAST WARNING</summary>
                        <ul>
                          haha made you look
                        </ul>
                      </details>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </details>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </details>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="sunken-panel" id="about-table">
        <table class="interactive">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class="content-file" id="about-file">
                <img id="notes-icon" src="message_file-0.png"> about.txt
              </td>
              <td class="content-file" id="project-file-1">
                <img id="notes-icon" src="message_file-0.png"> Project 1
              </td>
              <td class="content-file" id="project-file-2">
                <img id="notes-icon" src="message_file-0.png"> Project 2
              </td>
              <td class="content-file" id="project-file-3">
                <img id="notes-icon" src="message_file-0.png"> Project 3
              </td>
              <td class="content-file" id="contact-file">
                <img id="notes-icon" src="message_file-0.png"> contact.txt
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="status-bar" id="status-bar">
      <p class="status-bar-field" id="objects"><span></span> object(s)</p>
      <p class="status-bar-field" id="memory-space">
        <span></span>KB
      </p>
      <p class="status-bar-field" id="selected-name">
        <span></span>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="overlay"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Normally you don't add/remove CSS files with JavaScript but more use the smallest CSS that achieves your goal.  Toggling of elements visually is a common thing and can be done simply with limited CSS (couple lines) and simple element changes - either data element attribute values (my current preference) or toggling classes.  Note this does not dissuade you from using ajax to load CSS also which appears to be what you are attempting perhaps?

Comment: Made snippet of code.  Note error eventually when clicking `{
  "message": "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'remove')",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 306,
  "colno": 15
}`  FWIW this is a really non-standard UI for a web page

Comment: Yes that was what I was attempting. I do like the idea of using data attributes as that is what I used to make the modal.

Comment: I'm not sure what could cause that error, I updated the snippet since it was a bit outdated. And yes it is, I just wanted to test out this design system I found.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Your basic error was checking for `null` not any negative for example "undefined" - so changed that to just use the "falsy" of JavaScript with `!modal` condition.

You also had multiple duplicate ids for icons so I made those a class instead.  Probably a lot more ids than needed here but not my choice.

Note how I toggle using data attributes and then use CSS to target those by value - you can have multiple "states" for example I used "blue" just to illustrate.

Not really "files" here but classes and ids with "file" in names.

```js
const openModalButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-modal-target]');
const closeModalButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-close-button]');
const overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');
const openAboutTab = document.getElementById('about-tab');
const openProjectsTab = document.getElementById('projects-tab');
const openContactTab = document.getElementById('contact-tab');
const modalStates = {
  active: "active",
  inactive: "inactive",
  blue: "blue"
};

function openModal(modal) {
  //console.log("Open:", modal);
  if (!modal) {
    //console.log("woops");
    return;
  }
  modal.dataset.isactive = modalStates.blue;
  //console.log("after:", modal);
  overlay.dataset.isactive = modalStates.active;
}

function closeModal(modal) {
  if (!modal) {
    return;
  }
  modal.dataset.isactive = modalStates.inactive;
  overlay.dataset.isactive = modalStates.inactive;
}

openModalButtons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    const modal = document.querySelector(event.target.dataset.modalTarget);
    openModal(modal);
  });
});

overlay.addEventListener('click', () => {
// whatever dataset value just close them - assumes have any "isactive" value
  const modals = document.querySelectorAll(".modal-container[data-isactive]");
  modals.forEach(modal => {
    closeModal(modal);
  });
});

closeModalButtons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    const modal = event.target.closest('.modal-container');
    closeModal(modal);
  });
});

function addContent(contentFile) {
  if (!contentFile) {
    return;
  }
  contentFile.add();
}

function removeContent(contentFile) {
  if (!contentFile) {
    return;
  }
  contentFile.remove();
}

let grabFiles = document.getElementsByClassName("content-file");

function findFile(specificContentFile) {
  let foundFile = grabFiles[specificContentFile];
  for (let i = 0; i < grabFiles.length; i++) {
    if (grabFiles[i] !== foundFile) {
      removeContent(grabFiles[i]);
    }
  }
}

openAboutTab.addEventListener('click', () => {
  findFile("about-file");
});

openProjectsTab.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const about = document.getElementById("about-file");
  removeContent(about);
  const contact = document.getElementById("contact-file");
  removeContent(contact);
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 16px;
}

* {
  font-family: "MS Sans Serif", Arial;
}

[data-modal-target="#modal"] {
  padding: 0.5em;
  font-size: 2em;
  border: solid 1px #00FF0040;
  margin: 1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: #0000FF20;
}

#menu-list {
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.menu-item {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0 3px;
}

.menu-item::first-letter {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.menu {
  margin: 3px;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.status-bar {
  column-gap: 2px;
}

#all-folders {
  max-width: 40%
}

#contents {
  max-width: 60%;
}

#status-bar {
  gap: 2px;
  row-gap: 2px;
}

#objects {
  width: 45%;
}

#memory-space {
  width: 20%;
}

#selected-name {
  width: 35%;
}

.modal-container {
  z-index: 10;
  min-width: 40%;
  max-width: 80%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
}

.modal-container[data-isactive="active"] {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
}

.modal-container[data-isactive="inactive"] {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
}

.modal-container[data-isactive="blue"] {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
  border: solid blue 2px;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1.5px;
  width: 100%;
}

.tree-view {
  width: 40%;
  max-width: 40%;
}

.sunken-panel {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60%;
}

#overlay,
#overlay[data-isactive="inactive"] {
  position: fixed;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  pointer-events: none;
}

#overlay[data-isactive="active"] {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: all;
}

li:focus {
  outline: 1px dotted #000000;
}

.tree-view {
  cursor: default;
}

tr {
  display: flex;
  margin: 2px 2px;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.content-file {
  min-height: 48px;
  max-height: 48px;
  padding: 6px 6px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: fit-content;
}

.notes-icon {
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 3.5px auto;
  max-height: 32px;
  max-width: 32px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/98.css" />
  <!--  commented out and included in snippet  <link rel="stylesheet" href="modal.css"/>
    <script defer src="modal.js"></script>
    -->
</head>

<body>
  <a data-modal-target="#modal">test</a>
  <div class="modal-container" id="modal">
    <div class="title-bar">
      <div class="title-bar-text">A Window With A Status Bar</div>
      <div class="title-bar-controls">
        <button aria-label="Help"></button>
        <button data-close-button aria-label="Close" class="close-button"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
      <ul id="menu-list">
        <li class="menu-item">File</li>
        <li class="menu-item">Edit</li>
        <li class="menu-item">View</li>
        <li class="menu-item">Tools</li>
        <li class="menu-item">Help</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="status-bar" id="status-bar">
      <p class="status-bar-field" id="all-folders">All Folders</p>
      <p class="status-bar-field" id="contents">
        Contents of '<span></span>'
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <ul class="tree-view" id="folder-list">
        <li>
          <details open>
            <summary>My Computer</summary>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <details open>
                  <summary>(C:)</summary>
                  <ul class="tree-view-folders">
                    <li><a id="about-tab">about</a></li>
                    <li><a id="projects-tab">projects</a></li>
                    <li><a id="contact-tab">contact</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </details>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </details>
        </li>
        <li>
          <details open>
            <summary>Secret Documents</summary>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <details>
                  <summary>DO NOT OPEN</summary>
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                      <details closed>
                        <summary>LAST WARNING</summary>
                        <ul>
                          haha made you look
                        </ul>
                      </details>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </details>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </details>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="sunken-panel" id="about-table">
        <table class="interactive">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class="content-file" id="about-file">
                <img class="notes-icon" src="message_file-0.png">about.txt
              </td>
              <td class="content-file" id="project-file-1">
                <img class="notes-icon" src="message_file-0.png">Project 1
              </td>
              <td class="content-file" id="project-file-2">
                <img class="notes-icon" src="message_file-0.png">Project 2
              </td>
              <td class="content-file" id="project-file-3">
                <img class="notes-icon" src="message_file-0.png">Project 3
              </td>
              <td class="content-file" id="contact-file">
                <img class="notes-icon" src="message_file-0.png">contact.txt
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="status-bar" id="status-bar">
      <p class="status-bar-field" id="objects"><span></span>object(s)</p>
      <p class="status-bar-field" id="memory-space">
        <span></span>KB
      </p>
      <p class="status-bar-field" id="selected-name">
        <span></span>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="overlay"></div>
</body>

</html>
```